# Cup Product Structure on the n-Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We know that The $k^{th}$ homology of the n-torus $(S^1)^n$ is generated by $\bigotimes_{i\in I}\lambda_i$ where $\lambda_i$ generates the first homology of the $i^{th}$ copy of $S^1$ and $I\subset\{1,2 ... n\}$ is an indexed set of cardinality $K$. Set $J=\{1,2...n\}\setminus I$ and $\alpha_j$ a generator the first cohomology of the $j^{th}$ copy of $S^1$

Then is it true that $\displaystyle\bigotimes_{i\in J}\lambda_j$ and $\displaystyle\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i$ are Poincar\'e dual to each other upto sign?

**UPDATE:** We know here that since the Ext and Tor groups vanish we must have that the cohomology groups are just Hom duals to the homology groups of the same dimension, so we can evaluate the cohomology class on the homology class.

With $I,J$ as above,$$1=(\smile_{1\le i\le n}\alpha_i)([(S^1)^n])=(-1)^k(\smile_{j\in J}\alpha_j)([(S^1)^n]\cap (\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i))$$

Also if we replace $J$ with $J'$ of the same cardinality, it will certainly intersect $I$, so that$$(\smile_{j\in J'}\alpha_j)([(S^1)^n]\cap (\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i))=(\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i)\smile(\smile_{j\in J'}\alpha_j)([(S^1)^n])=0$$

If we show\begin{equation}(\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_I)(\bigotimes_{i\in I'}\lambda_i)=\begin{cases}1&I'=I\\0&I'\ne I\end{cases}\end{equation} then we are necessarily done, because then we must have that the Poincar\'e dual $[(S^1)^n]\cap (\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i)$ to $(\smile_{i\in I}\alpha_i)$ is indeed $\bigotimes_{i\in J}\lambda_j$.

So our problem reduces to proving this result.

Comment: See the bottom of pp. 242: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATcapprod.pdf